# Swift/Xcode - Possible to reuse element(s) within a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionviewcell

This question will probably sound stupid, but is it possible to re-use an element in a `UICollectionViewCell`.

I have downloaded an array of images from Firebase. I have tested the length of the array `print(imagesArray.count)` an the output is `[0]` and `[1]` so I have two images in my array.

I have one single UIImageView.

I set images using this line of code -

```
 if let firstImageString = post?.firstPhotoURL {
        let firstImageURL = URL(string: firstImageString)
        photoImageView.sd_setImage(with: firstImageURL)

    }
```

Yes, I know it will only display the first image. But in my app, users can upload a maximum of 20 images/17 images and 3 videos. Am I required to have 20 image views, hide them and test to see if a value exists at the certain node i.e. `post?.firstPhotoURL`, `post?.secondPhotoURL`? Or is there another efficient way?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why is the array always 0 or 1? Normally you would use the `UICollectionViewDataSource` methods to setup the number of items in section based on the length of the array. And then, the `cellForItemAt` to setup each cell.

Comment: Not or. Its [0] and [1]. Which indicates the length of the array.I have done so, however, I only appear to get one ImageView. This may be down to the fact the array length is [1] which means two elements however, I am only getting 1 imageview when I'm looking for two haha.

Comment: This is strange. If you do a `count` on an `Array` you get an `int` value indicating the number of elements. So I assume your `imagesArray.count` should return 2, which means you have value `imagesArray[0]` and `imagesArray[1]`. Use `collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)` delegate method to return the `imagesArray.count` value.